# Android share menu : apps ordering

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I made an Android app which can receive text via `ACTION_SEND` intents from other apps. However, when I try to share content from another app, my app is in the bottom of the long list of available apps. It's not alphabetically ordered because my app begins with "A". So how can I do to raise the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of options is controlled by the UI showing those options. That might be a system-supplied UI (e.g., platform default chooser) or an in-app API (e.g., `ShareActionProvider`). You have no means of guaranteeing your app's position in those options in either case. Whether they use alphabetical order, frequency of use, or other criteria is up to their developers, not you.